# Aggregate function in an SQL update query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to set the value in one table to the sum of the values in another table.  Something along these lines:

```
UPDATE table1
SET field1 = SUM(table2.field2)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.field3 = table2.field3
GROUP BY table1.field3
```

Of course, as this stands, it won't work - `SET` doesn't support `SUM` and it doesn't support `GROUP BY`.

I should know this, but my mind's drawing a blank.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.field1 = t2.field2Sum
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN (select field3, sum(field2) as field2Sum
   from table2
  group by field3) as t2
on t2.field3 = t1.field3
```

Comment: I put the three queries side-by-side and ran an execution plan.  This answer had a cost of 5%.

Comment: Elegant, easy to implement...Where have you been all day??? I have been banging my head over it for more than an hour now :)

Comment: Important: Watch out if any of the fields you are grouping by might be nullable (eg. field3 above). you'd need to modify the 'join' to account for this or your sums will be inaccurate (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14366034/16940)

Comment: This is not working in postgresql. You must do it like in this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35393706/postgresql-update-using-aggregate-function

Answer (score 13):

Use:

```
UPDATE table1
   SET field1 = (SELECT SUM(t2.field2) 
                   FROM TABLE2 t2 
                  WHERE t2.field3 = field2)
```

Comment: I put the three queries side-by-side and ran an execution plan.  This answer had a cost of 44%.

Comment: this didn't work for me, because t2.filed3 was the same name as table1.field2, so the join performed behind the scenes didn't work properly.  (I assuem there's a join behind the scenes)

Answer (score 7):

A good situation to use CROSS APPLY

```
UPDATE t1
   SET t1.field1 = t2.field2Sum
  FROM table1 t1
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(field2) as field2Sum
                FROM table2 t2
               WHERE t2.field3 = t1.field3) AS t2
```

Comment: CROSS APPLY is elegant way and you can populate multiple columns as well.

Comment: I suggest to rename "t2" alias (CROSS APPLY product) into "f_sum" as you're applying a function against "t1" table. Using "t2" both as table2 alias and CROSS APPLY product alias can be misleading for the readers.

Answer (score 6):

Or you could use a mix of [JBrooks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/136059/jbrooks) and [OMG Ponies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135152/omg-ponies) answers:

```
UPDATE table1
   SET field1 = (SELECT SUM(field2)
                   FROM table2 AS t2
                  WHERE t2.field3 = t1.field3)
  FROM table1 AS t1
```

Comment: I put the three queries side-by-side and ran an execution plan.  This answer had a cost of 51%.

Comment: Okie dokie! And thanks for the feedback. I'll add it to my toolbox. :-)

Comment: That would be because you are using a SUBQUERY that must fire off the SUM() every row that is valid, even with the optimizer

Answer (score 4):

I know the question is tagged SQL Server but be careful with UPDATE with JOIN if you are using **PostgreSQL**. @JBrooks answer won't work :

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.field1 = t2.field2Sum
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN (...) as t2
on t2.field3 = t1.field3
```

You will have to adapt it to :

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET t1.field1 = t2.field2Sum
FROM (...) as t2
WHERE t2.field3 = t1.field3
```

See parameter `from_list` in the doc to get why `FROM` is considered by PostgreSQL as a self-join : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-update.html#AEN89239

Answer (score 3):

You can also use CTE like below.

```
;WITH t2 AS (
    SELECT field3, SUM(field2) AS field2
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY field3
)
UPDATE table1
SET table1.field1 = t2.field2
FROM table1
INNER JOIN t2 ON table1.field3 = t2.field3
```

Comment: I used to do the update with subquery till I faced a situation today where subquery table needed outer table for a join. This is what works best in that case.