# MySQL Join Issue

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I'm working on a political application for a client, and I've got two database tables. One has all the registered voters in a certain city, and the other has all the votes for each registered voter. Combined, these two tables number well over 7 million records. This site is coded on CakePHP.

I'm already narrowing the results by a number of criteria, but I need to filter it also based on the percentage of elections that a given voter has voted in since they registered. I have all the votes, the year they registered, and that there are 3 elections every 4 years. I've tried doing a subquery to filter the results, but it took far too long. It took 10 minutes to return 10 records. I have to do this in a join some way, but I'm not at all versed in joins.

This is basically what I need to do:

```
  SELECT * FROM voters 
     WHERE (number of votes voter has) >= (((year(now())-(registration_year) ) * 3/4)
     * (percentage needed))
```

All of that is pretty straight-forward. The trick is counting the votes the voter has from the votes database. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either create another table, or extend your first table (the one containing voter information, but not their votes) with two columns -- #votes and registrationAge. Then you can update this table by scanning the 'votes' table once -- everytime you encounter a vote, just increase the count.

Comment: that thought had never actually occured to me. That way, I actually don't need the voter history table. It's only for getting the number of elections that they've voted in, so I can just add the number of votes to the table. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to calculate this as part of your query

In a case where this info will only change 3 times in four years, I'd add the voted % field to the voter table and calculate it once after each election. Then you can simply filter by the field.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a vote_count field to voters table and do a update count on that. You might want to do it in straight sql query: [Aggregate function in an SQL update query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009927/aggregate-function-in-an-sql-update-query)

Also, I'm not sure if mysql smart enough to optimize this, but don't use year(now()): you can either get that value in PHP, or just hard code it each time you run (you probably don't need to run it too often).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT voters.* FROM voters
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(voterid) AS votes,voterid AS id FROM votes) AS a
         ON voters.id = a.id
     WHERE a.votes >= (((year(now())-(voters.registration_year) ) * 3/4) * percentage
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend to create a view, then model your vie to fetch the data