# SQL Server JOIN missing NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I had the following 2 tables:

```
      Table1:                                Table2:
Col1:      Col2:     Col3:             Col1:       Col2:       Col4:
a          b         c                 a           b           d
e          <null>    f                 e           <null>      g
h          i         j                 h           i           k
l          <null>    m                 l           <null>      n
o          <null>    p                 o           <null>      q
```

Now, I want to join these tables on `Col1` and `Col2` and bring back the entire set to look like:

```
     Result:
Col1:      Col2:     Col3:     Col4:
a          b         c         d
e          <null>    f         g
h          i         j         k
l          <null>    m         n
o          <null>    p         q
```

So, I tried a SQL like:

```
SELECT Table1.Col1, Table1.Col2, Table1.Col3, Table2.Col4
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
    ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1 
    AND Table1.Col2 = Table2.Col2
```

But it isn't matching the `NULL` values in `Col2`, so I end up with:

```
     Result:
Col1:      Col2:     Col3:     Col4:
a          b         c         d
h          i         j         k
```

How can I get the result I am looking for??

Thanks!

Comment: is this specific to sql-server? i can't seem to do this in postgres 11.5

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You can be explicit about the joins:

```
SELECT Table1.Col1, Table1.Col2, Table1.Col3, Table2.Col4
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN
     Table2
      ON (Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1 or Table1.Col1 is NULL and Table2.Col1 is NULL) AND
         (Table1.Col2 = Table2.Col2 or Table1.Col2 is NULL and Table2.Col2 is NULL)
```

In practice, I would be more likely to use `coalesce()` in the join condition:

```
SELECT Table1.Col1, Table1.Col2, Table1.Col3, Table2.Col4
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN
     Table2
     ON (coalesce(Table1.Col1, '') = coalesce(Table2.Col1, '')) AND
        (coalesce(Table1.Col2, '') = coalesce(Table2.Col2, ''))
```

Where `''` would be a value not in either of the tables.

Just a word of caution.  In most databases, using any of these constructs prevents the use of indexes.

Comment: another option for coalesce would be `ON (T1.C1=T2.C1 or (coalesce(T1.C1,T2.C1) is null)) and (T1.C2=T2.C2 or (coalesce(T1.C2,T2.C2) is null))`

Comment: This doesn't work in the case where you have `Table1=(a,b,c)(a,null,d) Table2=(a,b,e)`.  In this case, the join matches the case `Table1(a,null,d)` with the nonexistent case `Table2(a,null,null)`.  This should not result in a match.

Comment: In other words, this does not distinguish between cases where there is a `NULL` in `Table2.Col2` which matches, versus no record at all in `Table2`.

Comment: Shouldn't join conditions be like below with null checks as a single unit after or operator. (Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1 or (Table1.Col1 is NULL and Table2.Col1 is NULL)) AND (Table1.Col2 = Table2.Col2 or (Table1.Col2 is NULL and Table2.Col2 is NULL))

Comment: In T-SQL, using `COALESCE()` in a `JOIN` is way slower than explicitly checking `NULL`

Answer (score 51):

Use Left Outer Join instead of Inner Join to include rows with NULLS.

```
SELECT Table1.Col1, Table1.Col2, Table1.Col3, Table2.Col4
FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 
    ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1 
    AND Table1.Col2 = Table2.Col2
```

For more information, see here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190409(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Works  for me. Easy and clean.

Comment: This does not answer the original question. your solution will include null rows for table2 if no match found. look at second row in both tables in OP's question

Comment: This doesn't really solve the question as you'd now have to filter to select the values you want.  To do that you'll have contend with the nulls again.

Comment: Thanks for good advice, thats what i have needed. My case was Table.Col1 was null and there was no null record in Table2 at all, so it wasn't select that row with null col at all.

Answer (score 18):

Try using `ISNULL` function:

```
SELECT Table1.Col1, Table1.Col2, Table1.Col3, Table2.Col4
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2
   ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1 
   AND ISNULL(Table1.Col2, 'ZZZZ') = ISNULL(Table2.Col2,'ZZZZ')
```

Where `'ZZZZ'` is some arbitrary value never in the table.

Comment: This introduces magic values which I tend to avoid unless absolutely necessary

Comment: This would work nicely, but assumes that '0' isn't used elsewhere in another row.

Comment: Yeah, I prefer @Gordon's reply, just offering an alternative.  And I'd probably use a different value that I knew couldn't be represented in the return values like 'ZZZZ' or something :-)

Comment: This doesn't distinguish between cases where `Table2.Col2 IS NULL` versus cases where there is no matching record in `Table2`.

Answer (score 17):

Dirty and quick hack:

```
SELECT Table1.Col1, Table1.Col2, Table1.Col3, Table2.Col4
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1
 AND ((Table1.Col2 = Table2.Col2) OR (Table1.Col2 IS NULL AND Table2.Col2 IS NULL))
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jap - Exactly what i was looking for... Gordon beat you to it, but thanks for answering this!

Comment: This solution is neither dirty nor a hack.
It is simply the correct way to do it in T-SQL.

Answer (score 1):

you can just map like that

```
select * from tableA a
join tableB b on isnull(a.colID,'') = isnull(b.colId,'')
```

Comment: This is problematic, because it doesn't differentiate between an empty string an an actual NULL value.

In case a.colD is an empty string and b.colID is NULL the comparison would still evaluate to true, even though the two columns contain different values.

In some cases you don't want to treat NULL and an empty string as being equal.

Answer (score 1):

for some reason I couldn't get it to work with the outer join.

So I used:

```
SELECT * from t1 where not Id in (SELECT DISTINCT t2.id from t2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @Table1 as Table(Col1 varchar(1),Col2 varchar(1), Col3 varchar(1))
declare @Table2 as Table(Col1 varchar(1),Col2 varchar(1), Col4 varchar(1))
insert into @Table1
values('a',          'b',     'c'),
('e',          null,    'f'), 
('h',          'i'  ,   'j'), 
('l',          null  ,  'm'), 
('o',          null  ,  'p') 
insert into @Table2
values('a',          'b',     'd'),
('e',          null,    'g'), 
('h',          'i'  ,   'k'), 
('l',          null  ,  'n'), 
('o',          null  ,  'q') 


select * from @Table1 tbl1
join @Table2 tbl2
on tbl1.Col1 =tbl2.Col1
and isnull(tbl1.Col2,0) =isnull(tbl2.Col2,0)
```

output:

```
 Col1   Col2    Col3    Col1    Col2    Col4
 a      b       c       a       b       d
 e      NULL    f       e       NULL    g
 h      i       j       h       i       k
 l      NULL    m       l       NULL    n
 o      NULL    p       o       NULL    q
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using additional condition in join:

```
SELECT Table1.Col1, Table1.Col2, Table1.Col3, Table2.Col4
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2
ON (Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1 
    OR (Table1.Col1 IS NULL AND Table2.Col1 IS NULL)
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

The only correct answer is not to join columns with null values. This can lead to unwanted behaviour very quickly.

e.g. isnull(b.colId,''): What happens if you have empty strings in your data? The join maybe duplicate rows which I guess is not intended in this case.

Comment: I disagree.
The correct answer is not to avoid joining nullable columns.
The correct answer is to do the comparison in the JOIN correctly (as demonstrated in the other answers to this question).

Comment: You are right David, but I think that we can agree on the fact that the ISNULL solution is really bad practice.

Comment: Yes, the ISNULL solution is not a good idea.
Using magic values is generally problematic, especially in this situation.
Using ISNULL in this situation is neither necessary nor advisable.

NULL does have a special meaning in T-SQL.
It means that the value is *unknown*.
That is very different from any other possible value.

Therefore SQL Server treats NULL very differently than any other value and one should generally not attempt to treat NULL the same as any other value.

Answer (score 0):

Some SQL implementations have a special Null-safe equal operator.

For instance Snowflake has [EQUAL_NULL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/equal_null.html) so ou can do

```sql
SELECT 
  Table1.Col1, Table1.Col2, Table1.Col3, Table2.Col4 
FROM 
  Table1 
  INNER JOIN Table2 ON EQUAL_NULL(Table1.Col1, Table2.Col1) 
  AND EQUAL_NULL(Table1.Col2, Table2.Col2)
```