# Please help me with these pesky joins

Tags: sql, ms-access

Let's say I have 2 tables, one with 3 fields (id, name, num), the other has two (id, num).

t1 :

```
1       | assassin  | #1
1       | assassin  | #2  
2       | vampire   | (null) 
3       | zombie    | #1
3       | zombie    | #2
(null)  | zombie    | #3
4       | wizard    | (null)
```

t2 :

```
1       | #1
1       | #2  
2       | (null)
3       | #1
3       | #2
(null)  | #3
4       | (null)
```

I tried to join these tables:

```
SELECT      t2.id, t1.name, t2.num 
FROM        t1 
INNER JOIN  t2  ON  t2.id = t1.id 
                AND t2.num = t1.num
```

When I execute this statement, the table shows only the records that has no null values. Why? What's the correct way to join these 2 tables? Is it proper to inner join tables on two conditions? (am using vb.net & ms access btw).

Comment: null means unknown, so they will not match in a join. if you want them to match you need to use the expression `is null`, but you also need to decide whether null on one side matches everything on the other side or only nulls on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Left Join` instead of `Inner Join`.

The `Inner Join` only returns rows that are joined.

The `Left Join` returns all rows from the "left" table, regardless if they join onto the other table.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an `inner join` on `null` values because `null` doesn't match itself (`null = null` returns false, IOW). You need to use an `outer join` instead.

See [this SQL Server answer on joining with nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366004/sql-server-join-missing-null-values)