# Left join returning different results when changing column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_ETS) AS compte,ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_GREFFE
FROM ENTREPRISES 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISSEMENTS ON ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_ENTREPRISE = ENTREPRISES.IU_ENTREPRISE
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.BASES ON dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_BASE = dbo.BASES.IU_BASE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ETATS ON dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_ETAT = dbo.ETATS.IU_ETAT
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.NAF ON dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_NAF_ECO = dbo.NAF.IU_NAF 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ADRESSES ON ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_ADR_PHY = ADRESSES.IU_ADR
LEFT OUTER JOIN PARTENAIRES ON 
(PARTENAIRES.IU_PART = Etablissements.IU_GREFFE OR Etablissements.IU_GREFFE IS NULL)
WHERE (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.SIREN IS NOT NULL) 
AND (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.SIREN <> '') 
AND (dbo.ENTREPRISES.FLG_HISTORISE <> '1') 
AND (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.NIC IS NOT NULL) 
AND (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.NIC <> '') 
AND (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.GESTDEL = '1') 
AND (dbo.BASES.CODE = 'J1') 
AND (dbo.ETATS.LIBEL = 'Actif') 
AND (dbo.NAF.NAF NOT LIKE '000%') 
AND (dbo.ENTREPRISES.GESTDEL = '1')
AND PARTENAIRES.IU_TYPE_PART = '3'
GROUP BY ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_GREFFE
```

The aim is to flag the `NULL` and have them counted (see below).

```
  compte |  IU_GREFFE
  -------------------
  2      |  115
  1      |  126
  4875   |  26
  1      |  813
  21     |  2021
  36     |  5559
  6      |  149
  11661  |  27
  14904  |  130
  1      |  1298
  13402  |  25
  15790  |  NULL
  1      |  54
  11080  |  120
  9      |  423
  1      |  14
```

I want something neater than just having a count with a number, to have the libel like below

```
  compte |  Greffes
  ------------------
  2      |  Stack
  1      |  Morris
  4875   |  Dembe
  1      |  Dallas
  21     |  Delhi
  36     |  Rohintra
  6      |  Zheng
  11661  |  Liliane
  14904  |  T-shirt
  1      |  Star
  13402  |  Yes
  15790  |  NULL
  1      |  Whatsapp
  11080  |  Enkai
  9      |  Algérie
  1      |  Hewah
```

I change my query to have the name of the `greffes`, I'm interested in

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_ETS) AS compte,PARTENAIRES.LIBEL AS Greffes 
-- changing the ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_GREFFE to PARTENAIRES.LIBEL
FROM ENTREPRISES 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISSEMENTS ON ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_ENTREPRISE = ENTREPRISES.IU_ENTREPRISE
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.BASES ON dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_BASE = dbo.BASES.IU_BASE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ETATS ON dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_ETAT = dbo.ETATS.IU_ETAT
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.NAF ON dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_NAF_ECO = dbo.NAF.IU_NAF 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ADRESSES ON ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_ADR_PHY = ADRESSES.IU_ADR
LEFT OUTER JOIN PARTENAIRES 
ON (PARTENAIRES.IU_PART = Etablissements.IU_GREFFE OR Etablissements.IU_GREFFE IS NULL)
WHERE (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.SIREN IS NOT NULL) 
AND (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.SIREN <> '') 
AND (dbo.ENTREPRISES.FLG_HISTORISE <> '1') 
AND (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.NIC IS NOT NULL) 
AND (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.NIC <> '') 
AND (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.GESTDEL = '1') 
AND (dbo.BASES.CODE = 'J1') 
AND (dbo.ETATS.LIBEL = 'Actif') 
AND (dbo.NAF.NAF NOT LIKE '000%') 
AND (dbo.ENTREPRISES.GESTDEL = '1')
AND PARTENAIRES.IU_TYPE_PART = '3'
GROUP BY PARTENAIRES.LIBEL
```

Instead of giving me the desired result, I have the result below (just giving you a tiny sample of the results as there are 284 lines )

```
   compte    |Greffes
   -------------------
   15790     |Mooshi
   15790     |Bazoo
   15790     |NouYawk
   15790     |Matamata
```

Thinking about it, the issue most likely lies with the null part as I have added this extra clause on the

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN PARTENAIRES ON 
(PARTENAIRES.IU_PART = Etablissements.IU_GREFFE OR Etablissements.IU_GREFFE IS NULL)
```

And the part below most specifically

```
 OR Etablissements.IU_GREFFE IS NULL
```

And looking at the results, 15790 is the null part.

I'm not sure what I can do to sort that out as I'm already using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to retrieve the `NULL`

As another variation, I tried to put the 2nd query into a nested query and do a join with the `partenaires` table but it gives me the same issue.

Any insights are more than welcomed

Thanks

**update**: Thinking about it, I can use a `case` to manually give the `iu_greffe` a proper libel but still, I would like to be able to sort the issue without going too much into manual tweaking. And to be honest, I hate being stuck into something I cannot resolve.

Comment: what about full outer join on last table and without null condition?

Comment: Hi @nada, nope it does not do the trick and i've done that too -_-

Comment: You have conditions in the WHERE clause that are from tables in the LEFT OUTER JOINS. That essentially makes the join into just JOIN. Move the condition to the JOIN : LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.BASES ON dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_BASE = dbo.BASES.IU_BASE  AND (dbo.BASES.CODE = 'J1')

Comment: Hi @jim31415 now we are talking. :) I did what you advised but nope, it does not do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use **with** clause

```
with t as
(
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_ETS) AS compte,ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_GREFFE
FROM ENTREPRISES 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISSEMENTS ON ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_ENTREPRISE = ENTREPRISES.IU_ENTREPRISE
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.BASES ON dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_BASE = dbo.BASES.IU_BASE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ETATS ON dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_ETAT = dbo.ETATS.IU_ETAT
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.NAF ON dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_NAF_ECO = dbo.NAF.IU_NAF 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ADRESSES ON ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_ADR_PHY = ADRESSES.IU_ADR
LEFT OUTER JOIN PARTENAIRES ON 
(PARTENAIRES.IU_PART = Etablissements.IU_GREFFE OR Etablissements.IU_GREFFE IS NULL)
WHERE (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.SIREN IS NOT NULL) 
AND (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.SIREN <> '') 
AND (dbo.ENTREPRISES.FLG_HISTORISE <> '1') 
AND (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.NIC IS NOT NULL) 
AND (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.NIC <> '') 
AND (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.GESTDEL = '1') 
AND (dbo.BASES.CODE = 'J1') 
AND (dbo.ETATS.LIBEL = 'Actif') 
AND (dbo.NAF.NAF NOT LIKE '000%') 
AND (dbo.ENTREPRISES.GESTDEL = '1')
AND PARTENAIRES.IU_TYPE_PART = '3'
GROUP BY ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_GREFFE
)
select t.compte, PARTENAIRES.LIBEL AS Greffes
from t
LEFT OUTER JOIN PARTENAIRES 
ON (PARTENAIRES.IU_PART = t.IU_GREFFE)
where PARTENAIRES.IU_TYPE_PART = '3'
```

Comment: Hi @Proggear, you are the man! Can you tell me more about what you've done, please? Your code is working but you will need to remove the `where PARTENAIRES.IU_TYPE_PART = '3'`

Comment: with clause let's you use query as part of bigger one. Here result of query inside 
with t as ( .. ) 
used to make next query. You can think about t as table with result of inner select.

Answer (score 1):

When you are tired, you are messing up. This is what I've done earlier and I thought as not working

```
SELECT t.compte, PARTENAIRES.LIBEL AS Greffes
FROM 
(
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_ETS) AS compte,ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_GREFFE
FROM ENTREPRISES 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISSEMENTS ON ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_ENTREPRISE = ENTREPRISES.IU_ENTREPRISE
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.BASES ON dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_BASE = dbo.BASES.IU_BASE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ETATS ON dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_ETAT = dbo.ETATS.IU_ETAT
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.NAF ON dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_NAF_ECO = dbo.NAF.IU_NAF 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ADRESSES ON ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_ADR_PHY = ADRESSES.IU_ADR
LEFT OUTER JOIN PARTENAIRES ON 
(PARTENAIRES.IU_PART = Etablissements.IU_GREFFE OR Etablissements.IU_GREFFE IS NULL)
WHERE (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.SIREN IS NOT NULL) 
AND (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.SIREN <> '') 
AND (dbo.ENTREPRISES.FLG_HISTORISE <> '1') 
AND (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.NIC IS NOT NULL) 
AND (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.NIC <> '') 
AND (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.GESTDEL = '1') 
AND (dbo.BASES.CODE = 'J1') 
AND (dbo.ETATS.LIBEL = 'Actif') 
AND (dbo.NAF.NAF NOT LIKE '000%') 
AND (dbo.ENTREPRISES.GESTDEL = '1')
AND PARTENAIRES.IU_TYPE_PART = '3'
GROUP BY ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_GREFFE
) AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN PARTENAIRES 
ON (PARTENAIRES.IU_PART = t.IU_GREFFE)
```

But it actually does ...

Thanks to @proggear for his answer

Answer (score 1):

A. If you set conditions other than `is null` on join table then `left join` doesn't make sense.

> LEFT OUTER JOIN PARTENAIRES ON (PARTENAIRES.IU_PART = Etablissements.IU_GREFFE OR Etablissements.IU_GREFFE IS NULL)
>       ...
>       AND PARTENAIRES.IU_TYPE_PART = '3'

B. Run two queries to better understand what you have

1. > LEFT OUTER JOIN PARTENAIRES ON 
   >   (PARTENAIRES.IU_PART = Etablissements.IU_GREFFE)
2. > LEFT OUTER JOIN PARTENAIRES ON 
   >   (Etablissements.IU_GREFFE IS NULL)

I bet (1) will return empty result and (2) 15790 in all rows.

Comment: Hi @Alex-kudryashev, `1` gives me 15790 in all rows and `2` gives me something similar to 1, not in all rows but in almost all of them. Gordon Linoff provided this very good answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366004/sql-server-join-missing-null-values

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the original query and change the column name on the outer one.

```
select compte, IU_GREFFE as Greffes from (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_ETS) AS compte,ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_GREFFE
    FROM ENTREPRISES 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISSEMENTS ON ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_ENTREPRISE = ENTREPRISES.IU_ENTREPRISE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.BASES ON dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_BASE = dbo.BASES.IU_BASE 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ETATS ON dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_ETAT = dbo.ETATS.IU_ETAT
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.NAF ON dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_NAF_ECO = dbo.NAF.IU_NAF 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ADRESSES ON ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_ADR_PHY = ADRESSES.IU_ADR
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PARTENAIRES ON 
    (PARTENAIRES.IU_PART = Etablissements.IU_GREFFE OR Etablissements.IU_GREFFE IS NULL)
    WHERE (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.SIREN IS NOT NULL) 
    AND (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.SIREN <> '') 
    AND (dbo.ENTREPRISES.FLG_HISTORISE <> '1') 
    AND (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.NIC IS NOT NULL) 
    AND (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.NIC <> '') 
    AND (dbo.ETABLISSEMENTS.GESTDEL = '1') 
    AND (dbo.BASES.CODE = 'J1') 
    AND (dbo.ETATS.LIBEL = 'Actif') 
    AND (dbo.NAF.NAF NOT LIKE '000%') 
    AND (dbo.ENTREPRISES.GESTDEL = '1')
    AND PARTENAIRES.IU_TYPE_PART = '3'
    GROUP BY ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_GREFFE
) as t
```

Comment: Hi @vijay, you did not understand correctly. Read my question again. I tried your solution already as I said in a `nested loop `and even with a join and it does not do what it should do

Comment: why do you have distinct in count instead of counting all? (in COUNT(DISTINCT ETABLISSEMENTS.IU_ETS) AS compte)

Comment: if I don't do a distinct, I have even more results.This is the why

Comment: I have the same number of lines e.g 284