# Codeigniter Model, getting value from 2 tables based on table1. If no value found on table2 then value return null

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join

I will explain my condition first
So i have 2 tables, one is table tb_form, second is tb_pendaftaran

```
tb_form         tb_pendaftaran
id_form         id_pendaftaran
judul           id_form
value           value
```

then i want to show all judul from tb_form, and get the value from tb_pendaftaran.

In case 1 : tb_form have 5 id_form, and all the id_form is in tb_pendaftaran too. it works fine, all the record showed up

In case 2 :
but the problem now is that when tb_form have 5 id_form, and tb_pendaftaran only have 3 of the ids, the result only show 3 records not five.
I wanted to show all the five judul based on table one, and if it doesnt have value from tb_pendaftaran, then the value should show nothing

*sorry for my poor english

Thankyou, and help is apreciated

Comment: Without seeing your code it's impossible to give an exact answer, but basically you need to `LEFT JOIN` the two tables instead of `INNER JOIN`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366004/sql-server-join-missing-null-values

Answer (score 0):

[There](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) is a nice graph for sql joins. Just look at the bottom of the page.

In your case you should use the following sql phrase:

```
select f.*, p.id_pendaftaran, p.value from tb_form f 
left join tb_pendaftaran p on f.id_form = p.id_form
```

So, you will list all of the rows on first table and if there are any matches on table tb_pendaftaran the related columns will be filled up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi Raven Please try the below code once.

$CI->db->from('tb_form');
$CI->db->join('tb_pendaftaran', 'tb_pendaftaran.id_form = tb_form.id_form', 'left');

Thanks,
Lavish Tyagi