# Is there a command which combines the functionalities of UNION and JOIN in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sqlite

What I mean is, say for example I have a query which combines results from two tables `A` and `B`; where `A` has some columns identical to `B` but a couple of different ones and the same goes for `B`. Is there a command which can merge the data in the identical columns (UNION) but concatenate the different columns in the final result (JOIN) or I'll have to do it the tedious way?

Would prefer an answer tailored for SQLite or Postgresql but any other is okay.

---

EDIT:

Say table `A` has the following columns:

```
ID    Source    Destination    Timestamp
```

And table `B` has the following columns:

```
ID    Source    Destination    Group    Read
```

I would want table `C` (the query) to have the following columns with the mutually exclusive columns having `NULL` values in both cases:

```
ID    Source    Destination    Timestamp    Group    Read
```

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN?

Comment: @jarlh Not exactly (I think), let me put example tables to clarify

Comment: UNION ALL with NULL placeholders for the columns that are not in both?

Comment: The example tables don't help without seeing the *data* in them.

Comment: @LukStorms yes, though I thought UNION ALL works when there identical column numbers and types in both tables

Comment: @Garikai Yes, that's why sometimes that trick from Olivier's answer could be used.  But also look into what FULL JOIN does.

Comment: @LukStorms Will take a look at those

Comment: Another tip, `UNION` doesn't show duplicate records. But `UNION ALL` just sticks the results together without discarding dups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make a union of two tables that only have partially equal columns, then you must fill the missing columns of the respective tables with NULL or other default values. E.g.

- Table X with columns A, B, C, D, E
- Table Y with columns A, B, C, F

```sql
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, '' AS F
FROM X
UNION ALL
SELECT A, B, C, '' AS D, NULL AS E, F
FROM Y
```

Use UNION (without ALL) if you want to eliminate duplicates. There can only be duplicates where the extra columns match the default values used for the other table.

---

Another approach is to join on the matching columns to eliminate duplicates on these columns

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(X.A, Y.A) AS A,
    COALESCE(X.B, Y.B) AS B,
    COALESCE(X.C, Y.C) AS C,
    X.D,
    X.E,
    Y.F
FROM
    X
    FULL OUTER JOIN Y
        ON X.A = Y.A AND
           X.B = Y.B AND
           X.C = Y.C
```

This is probably what matches your idea of combining UNION and JOIN the best. Unlike the UNION approach, this merges rows with equal A, B and C.

Note that you have to use a [FULL OUTER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp) to include the results of both tables, even if the corresponding record is missing from the other table. Not all SQL dialects have an outer join.

The [coalesce function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp) has different names in different dialects.

You might also encounter the [JOIN missing NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366004/sql-server-join-missing-null-values) problem when joining on NULL values.