# Update record in sql table with a sum of values from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Im new to SQL. I have a table `employee`, it has fields `eID` and `eLoad`. In addition i have table `ongoing_projects` it has `pID`, `eID` (those two are primary) and `eLoad`. Im trying to insert a sum of all `eLoad`s for each employee. I have an idea for pseudocode, but I cannot implement it. Any Ideas? Thank you!

```
For each eID in table employee
DO
UPDATE `employee` SET eload=(
  SELECT SUM (eload) as eload
  FROM ongoing_projects 
);
```

Comment: I think you will find the answer on -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009927/aggregate-function-in-an-sql-update-query :)

Comment: but how do I do "foreach eID"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood It, you would like to do something like:

```
UPDATE employee e
SET e.eLoad = (SELECT SUM(op.eLoad) FROM ongoing_projects op WHERE op.eID=e.eID);
```

It updates each row in `employees.eLoad` column with the sum of the `ongoing_projects.eLoad` where the ongoing_projects.eID=actual employee eID

Or if you would like to SUM `employees.eLoad` with the `ongoing_projects eLoad` then the query may look:

```
UPDATE employee e
SET e.eLoad = e.eLoad + (SELECT SUM(op.eLoad) FROM ongoing_projects op WHERE op.eID=e.eID);
```

Comment: Thank you! Just to be clear ( as I said I'm new to it) when I run your first querry - if i have employee with eID 111 it will set into employee.eload the sum of eload from projects where eID = 111, and it will be done for each eID in employee???

Comment: Yes this does this what you described