# Set values in table based on minimum from groups in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a new table in pgAdmin using SQL, and since I'm a total novice I'm running into problems.  My goal is to create a new table (called metadata) that summarizes values based on groupings from another table (called navigation).

Say the navigation table is like this:

```
VIDEO  LATITUDE
vid1   50
vid1   51
vid1   52
vid2   49
vid2   51
```

I need to create a metadata table that summarizes the navigation (with some other data); something like this:

```
VIDEO  minLATITUDE   LINK
vid1        50       http://foo
vid2        49       http://bar
```

I've been trying the SQL code (based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009927/aggregate-function-in-an-sql-update-query)):

```
UPDATE f1188hw.YTmeta as a
SET minLat = b.lat
FROM f1188hw.YTmeta
INNER JOIN (SELECT video, min(lat) AS lat
    from f1188hw.nav
    group by video) AS b
ON a.video = b.video;
```

And pgAdmin returns:

```
ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "a"
SQL state: 42P01
Hint: There is an entry for table "a", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
Character: 158
```

I'm guessing I'm missing something obvious, but haven't been able to find it through searching and reading through pgAdmin documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
UPDATE f1188hw.YTmeta as a
SET a.minLat = b.lat
FROM (SELECT video, min(lat) AS lat
      from f1188hw.nav
      group by video) AS b
WHERE a.video = b.video;
```

Or

```
UPDATE f1188hw.YTmeta
SET minLat = (SELECT min(lat) 
              from f1188hw.nav
              where f1188hw.YTmeta.video = video 
             )
```

Comment: The latter suggestion works great and looks much more concise than my attempt.