# Problems shortening a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to make a query that works with a temp table, work without that temp table

I tried doing a join in the subquery without the temp table but I don't get the same results as the query with the temp table.

This is the query with the temp table that works as I want:

```sql
create table #results(
    RowId       id_t,
    LastUpdatedAt date_T
)

insert into #results
select H.RowId, H.LastUpdatedAt from MemberCarrierMap M Join MemberCarrierMapHistory H on M.RowId = H.RowId

update MemberCarrierMap 
set CreatedAt = (select MIN(LastUpdatedAt) from #results r where r.rowId = MemberCarrierMap.rowId)
Where CreatedAt is null;
```

and here is the query I tried without the temp table that doesn't work like the above:

```sql
update MemberCarrierMap 
set CreatedAt = (select MIN(MH.LastUpdatedAt) from MemberCarrierMapHistory MH join MemberCarrierMap M on MH.RowId = M.RowId where MH.RowId = M.RowId )
Where CreatedAt is null;
```

I was expecting the 2nd query to work as the first but It is not. Any suggestions on how to achieve what the first query does without the temp table?

Comment: At a glance, they look like they would give the same results (although I think your WHERE clause in the 2nd query is redundant given the join). Can you describe how the results are different?

Comment: What is "date_T"?

Comment: The second query only gets the minimum for the whole table. The first one gets the minimum for that RowId. Thanks.

Comment: Date_t is a user defined datatype (datetime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
update M
set M.CreatedAt = (select MIN(MH.LastUpdatedAt) from MemberCarrierMapHistory MH WHERE MH.RowId = M.RowId)
FROM MemberCarrierMap M
Where M.CreatedAt is null;
```

Comment: The subquery needs to eb correlated with the main table being updated.

Comment: @PeterHe, you need to put 'set' statement before 'from' statement

Comment: @PeterHe yes change it to set statement before the from statement and I will accept the answer

Comment: Thanks@pwilcox and @H22 , too much mysql stuff recently.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is more or less a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009927/aggregate-function-in-an-sql-update-query) answer.  There, you will find multiple solutions.  But the ones that implement correlated subqueires are less performant than the one that simply uses an uncorrelated aggregation subquery inside a join.

Applying it to your situation, you will have this:

```
update    m
set       m.createdDate = hAgg.maxVal
from      memberCarrierMap m
join      (
             select   rowId, max(lastUpdatedAt) as maxVal
             from     memberCarrierMapHistory
             group by rowId
          ) as hAgg
          on m.rowId = hAgg.rowId
where     m.createdAt is null;
```

Basically, it's more performant because it is more expensive to run aggregations and filterings on a row-by-row basis (which is what happens in a correlated subquery) than to just get the aggregations out of the way all at once (joins tend to happen early in processing) and perform the match afterwards.